# Can I include a function inside of another function?

Tags: php, function, scope

Is it possible to include one function inside another? To learn functions, I'm trying to create a combat sequence using PHP. The sequence would look like this:

1. Dice would roll, assigning numbers to variables;
2. Hero1 attack results are printed;
3. Dice would roll, assigning numbers to variables;
4. Hereo2 attack results are printed;
5. Dice would roll, assigning numbers to variables;
6. Hero3 attack results are printed.

The dice rolling would be an automated function. Here is the code:

```
<?
rollSim();
combatSim();

function rollSim() {
    $hAttack = rand(1,20);
    $mDefend = rand(1,20);
    $mAttack = rand(1,20);
    $hDefend = rand(1,20);
    $mDamage = rand(10,25);
    $hDamage = rand(1,20);
} // end rollSim

function combatSim() {
    rollSim();
    if ($hAttack>$mDefend) {
        print "Hero hit monster for $hDamage damage.<br>";
    } else if ($hAttack<=$mDefend) {
        print "Hero missed monster.";
    }
} // end combatSim

?>
```

Answer (score 20):

Your `rollSim()` function should **return** the rolled numbers rather than setting some variables and trying to use them in your other function. I would return them in an associative array, like this:

```
function rollSim() {
    $roll['hAttack'] = rand(1,20);
    $roll['mDefend'] = rand(1,20);
    $roll['mAttack'] = rand(1,20);
    $roll['hDefend'] = rand(1,20);
    $roll['mDamage'] = rand(10,25);
    $roll['hDamage'] = rand(1,20);

    return $roll;
}

function combatSim() {
    $roll = rollSim();

    if ($roll['hAttack'] > $roll['mDefend']) {
        print "Hero hit monster for {$roll['hDamage']} damage.<br>";
    } else if ($roll['hAttack'] <= $roll['mDefend']) {
        print "Hero missed monster.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer; this is very very helpful. Quick follow-up question - will I be able to have the function "re-roll" each time? So, for example I would need a separate set of dice rolls for hero2 and hero3. Thank you again to everyone who has responded.

Comment: The body of the second if in combatSim isn't needed.  (I know you copied the OP's if; just wanted to mention.)

Comment: @Matt, Pass the results of the rolls as parameters to combatSim.

Comment: Yes, every time you call rollSim() you'll get a new set of dice rolls. You could do it like this for example: $hero1 = rollSim(); $hero2 = rollSim(); $hero3 = rollSim(); (And if there are any more heroes than this, make an array of heroes instead!)

Comment: This is great. I will need to work backwards through all this, but I've got everything I need now to keep learning and to get this to work. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't really do what you're asking.  Even if you embedded the declaration of `rollSim()` inside the definition of `combatSim()` (which you can do, that's legal but has no real effects), the variables you're setting in `rollSim()` would still be local to it and inaccessible by `combatSim()`.

You need a better way of passing around the information you're concerned with.  Jeremy Ruten details a good way.  Another way would be to define an object that's responsible for modeling your combat event and have `rollSim()` and `combatSim()` both be methods on it.

```
class myCombat {

    private $hAttack;
    private $mDefend;
    private $mAttack;
    private $hDefend;
    private $mDamage;
    private $hDamage;

    function rollSim() {
        $this->hAttack = rand(1, 20);
        $this->mDefend = rand(1, 20);
        $this->mAttack = rand(1, 20);
        $this->hDefend = rand(1, 20);
        $this->mDamage = rand(10, 25);
        $this->hDamage = rand(1, 20);
    }

    function combatSim() {
        $this->rollSim();
        if($this->hAttack > $this->mDefend)
            echo 'Hero hit monster for ' . $this->hDamage . ' damage.<br />';
        else
            echo 'Hero missed monster';
    }

}

$combat = new myCombat;
$combat->combatSim();
```

Comment: when you need functions inside of functions it's time to go OOP and make a class +1

Answer (score 5):

You can call functions from one another, certainly... but I think you want to use the scope of one in another, correct?

Sharing scope is a messy business. You're better off passing arguments.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to define functions within function in PHP you can do it like this:

```
function a()
{
    function b()
    {
        echo 'I am b';
    }
    function c()
    {
        echo 'I am c';
    }
}
a();
b();
c();
```

You must call the parent function first, then the functions inside.

Answer (score 3):

here is the simple example call function within function

```
class Percobaan{

  public function coba(){
    return "return value";
  }

  public function call(){
    //call coba function
    return $this->coba();
  }

} // end of class percobaan

//call the method
$klass = new Percobaan();
echo $klass->call();
```

the output willbe :

```
"return value"
```