# How to call method inside method in php

Tags: php

trying to run class method in class method callback.

class.php

```
<?php
namespace user;
class User {
    public function showUserAge( $age = 10 ) {
        echo $age;
    }
    public function showUserName( $name = 'arif', $fn ) {
        echo $name;
        call_user_func( $fn );
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

use user\User;

require './class.php';

$use = new User();

$use->showUserName( 'ARIF', function () {
    $use->showUserAge();
} );
```

ERROR:

> Warning: Undefined variable $use in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\index.php on line 9

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function showUserAge() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\class\class.php(9): call_user_func(Object(Closure)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\class\index.php(10): user\User->showUserName('ARIF', Object(Closure)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\index.php on line 9

Thank you!

Comment: I hope this shall help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708341/can-i-include-a-function-inside-of-another-function
Thank you!

Comment: You need to read up on variable scopes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php (the variable `$use` isn't accessible inside the anonymous function's scope).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike javascript, PHP doesn't automatically include outside variables in lambda functions - you will need to explicitly list the variables you want to allow using the "use" syntax.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

For example:

```php
$user = new User();

$user->showUserName( 'ARIF', function () use ($user) {
    $user->showUserAge();
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```php
class User {
    public function showUserAge( $age = 10 ) {
        echo $age;
    }
    public function showUserName( $name = 'arif', $fn ) {
        echo $name;
        
        if( method_exists( $this, $fn ) ) {
            $this->$fn();
        }
    }
}

$use = new User();

$use->showUserName( 'ARIF', "showUserAge" );
```